# Authentication service

Tags: php, authentication

This is the `AuthenticationService` I made based on Barry Jaspan's [design](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice), which is way better than the code of which I asked in a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/50925/making-my-user-model-class-code-more-modular-and-correct) a couple of months ago.

I would like it mainly reviewed on a couple of aspects:

- Readability (clean code)
- Accurate comments
- Accurate naming (especially for the last class)

**AuthenticationService.php**

```
namespace Model\Application;

use Http\HttpSession;
use Model\Infrastructure\Mapper\UserMapper;
use Model\Application\AuthenticationStorage;

/**
 * An authentication service.
 *
 * @author John Doe <john@doe.com>
 */
class AuthenticationService
{
    /**
     * @var HttpSession $httpSession An HttpSession instance.
     */
    private $httpSession;

    /**
     * @var UserMapper $userMapper A UserMapper instance.
     */
    private $userMapper;

    /**
     * @var AuthenticationStorage $authenticationStorage An AuthenticationStorage instance.
     */
    private $authenticationStorage;

    /**
     * Constructs the object.
     *
     * @param HttpSession            $httpSession           An HttpSession instance.
     * @param UserMapper             $userMapper            A UserMapper instance.
     * @param AuthenticationStorage  $authenticationStorage An AuthenticationStorage instance.
     */
    public function __construct(
        HttpSession           $httpSession,
        UserMapper            $userMapper,
        AuthenticationStorage $authenticationStorage
    ) {
        $this->httpSession            = $httpSession;
        $this->userMapper             = $userMapper;
        $this->authenticationStorage  = $authenticationStorage;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the authenticated User entity.
     *
     * @return User|void|null The User entity instance if found.
     */
    public function findAuthenticatedUser()
    {
        if ($identifier = $this->httpSession->findParameter('userIdentifier')) {
            return $this->userMapper->findByIdentifier($identifier);
        }

        if ($user = $this->authenticationStorage->authenticateUser()) {
            $this->httpSession->regenerateIdentifier();

            $this->httpSession->setParameter('userIdentifier', $user->getIdentifier());

            $this->authenticationStorage->updateAuthenticationData();

            return $user;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Authenticates a User entity.
     *
     * @param string  $email    An email address.
     * @param string  $password A password.
     * @param boolean $persist  True for authentication persistence, false if not. (optional)
     *
     * @return boolean True if authenticated, false if not.
     */
    public function authenticateUser($email, $password, $persist = false)
    {
        if ($user = $this->userMapper->findByEmail($email)) {
            if (password_verify($password, $user->getPassword())) {
                $this->httpSession->regenerateIdentifier();

                $this->httpSession->setParameter('userIdentifier', $user->getIdentifier());

                if ($persist) {
                    $this->authenticationStorage->storeAuthenticationData($user);
                }

                return true;
            }
        } else {
            // Prevent timing attacks.
            password_verify('password', '$2y$12$liVAn/nttQIipJI3LagCAOehLX0iamDjIn2WlX38ZEKS/dDHR3e1W');
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Deauthenticates the authenticated User entity.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function deauthenticateUser()
    {
        $this->httpSession->unsetParameter('userIdentifier');

        $this->httpSession->regenerateIdentifier();

        $this->authenticationStorage->deleteAuthenticationData();
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationStorage.php**

```
namespace Model\Application;

use Http\HttpCookies;
use Model\Domain\User\User;
use Library\CryptoRandCharGen;
use Model\Infrastructure\Mapper\UserMapper;
use Model\Domain\Authentication\Value\Token;
use Model\Domain\Authentication\Authentication;
use Model\Infrastructure\Mapper\AuthenticationMapper;
use Model\Domain\Authentication\AuthenticationFactory;

/**
 * Handles the authentication persistence of the authentication service.
 *
 * @author John Doe <john@doe.com>
 */
class AuthenticationStorage
{
    /**
     * @var HttpCookies $httpCookies An HttpCookies instance.
     */
    private $httpCookies;

    /**
     * @var AuthenticationMapper $authenticationMapper An AuthenticationMapper instance.
     */
    private $authenticationMapper;

    /**
     * @var UserMapper $userMapper A UserMapper instance.
     */
    private $userMapper;

    /**
     * @var AuthenticationFactory $authenticationFactory An AuthenticationFactory instance.
     */
    private $authenticationFactory;

    /**
     * Constructs the object.
     *
     * @param HttpCookies           $httpCookies           An HttpCookies instance.
     * @param AuthenticationMapper  $authenticationMapper  An AuthenticationMapper instance.
     * @param UserMapper            $userMapper            A UserMapper instance.
     * @param AuthenticationFactory $authenticationFactory An AuthenticationFactory instance.
     */
    public function __construct(
        HttpCookies           $httpCookies,
        AuthenticationMapper  $authenticationMapper,
        UserMapper            $userMapper,
        AuthenticationFactory $authenticationFactory
    ) {
        $this->httpCookies           = $httpCookies;
        $this->authenticationMapper  = $authenticationMapper;
        $this->userMapper            = $userMapper;
        $this->authenticationFactory = $authenticationFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Authenticates a User entity by the stored authentication data.
     *
     * @return User|boolean The User entity instance if authenticated, false if not.
     */
    public function authenticateUser()
    {
        if (!$cookie = $this->httpCookies->getParameter('auth')) {
            return false;
        }

        if (substr_count($cookie, ':') !== 2) {
            return false;
        }

        list($data['userIdentifier'], $data['seriesNumber'], $data['token']) = explode(':', $cookie);

        if (!$this->authenticationMapper->findAllByUserIdentifier($data['userIdentifier'])) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!($authentication = $this->authenticationMapper->findByIdentifier($data['userIdentifier'], $data['seriesNumber']) and password_verify($data['token'], $authentication->getToken()))) {
            $this->authenticationMapper->deleteAllByUserIdentifier($data['userIdentifier']);

            return false;
        }

        return $this->userMapper->findByIdentifier($authentication->getIdentifier()->getUserIdentifier());
    }

    /**
     * Generates authentication data for a User entity and stores it.
     *
     * @param User $user A User entity instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function storeAuthenticationData(User $user)
    {
        // Character pool for CryptoRandCharGen::generateString().
        $lowerAlpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        $upperAlpha = strtoupper($lowerAlpha);
        $digits     = '0123456789';
        $symbols    = './<>?;"\'`!@#$%^&*()[]{}_+=|\-';
        $characters = $lowerAlpha . $upperAlpha . $digits . $symbols;

        // Generate the authentication data.
        $seriesNumber       = CryptoRandCharGen::generateInteger(0, 2147483647);
        $token['cleartext'] = CryptoRandCharGen::generateString($characters, 60);
        $token['hash']      = password_hash($token['cleartext'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $registerDateTime   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        // Store it in the database.
        $authentication = $this->authenticationFactory->build($user->getIdentifier(), $seriesNumber, $token['hash'], $registerDateTime);
        $this->authenticationMapper->insert($authentication);

        // Issue a data with this data equivalent to the client.
        $auth   = $user->getIdentifier() . ':'. $seriesNumber . ':' . $token['cleartext'];
        $expiry = strtotime($registerDateTime . ' + 90 days');
        $this->httpCookies->setParameter('auth', $auth, $expiry, '/');
    }

    /**
     * Regenerates the authentication token for the found User entity and updates it.
     *
     * @return void|null
     */
    public function updateAuthenticationData()
    {
        if (!($cookie = $this->httpCookies->getParameter('auth') and substr_count($cookie, ':') === 2)) {
            return null;
        }

        list($data['userIdentifier'], $data['seriesNumber']) = explode(':', $cookie, -1);

        if (!$authentication = $this->authenticationMapper->findByIdentifier($data['userIdentifier'], $data['seriesNumber'])) {
            return null;
        }

        // Character pool for CryptoRandCharGen::generateString().
        $lowerAlpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        $upperAlpha = strtoupper($lowerAlpha);
        $digits     = '0123456789';
        $symbols    = './<>?;"\'`!@#$%^&*()[]{}_+=|\-';
        $characters = $lowerAlpha . $upperAlpha . $digits . $symbols;

        // Generate a new token.
        $token['cleartext'] = CryptoRandCharGen::generateString($characters, 60);
        $token['hash']      = password_hash($token['cleartext'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        // Update it in the database.
        $authentication->setToken(new Token($token['hash']));
        $this->authenticationMapper->update($authentication);

        // Issue a data with the updated data equivalent to the client.
        $auth   = $authentication->getIdentifier()->getUserIdentifier() . ':' . $authentication->getIdentifier()->getSeriesNumber() . ':' . $token['cleartext'];
        $expiry = strtotime($authentication->getRegisterDateTime() . ' + 90 days');
        $this->httpCookies->setParameter('auth', $auth, $expiry, '/');
    }

    /**
     * Deletes the found User entity its authentication data.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleteAuthenticationData()
    {
        if ($cookie = $this->httpCookies->getParameter('auth') and substr_count($cookie, ':') === 2) {
            list($data['userIdentifier'], $data['seriesNumber']) = explode(':', $cookie, -1);

            $this->authenticationMapper->deleteByIdentifier($data['userIdentifier'], $data['seriesNumber']);
        }

        $this->httpCookies->unsetParameter('auth');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to what [@janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64091/49695) said:

**`authenticateUser`**

Personally, I find these kind of fall-through nested if statements hard to read. It takes a while to see that `false` will be returned if the actual `password_verify` returns false.

If you write it like this, it would be clearer, and you would get rid of one level of nesting:

```
public function authenticateUser($email, $password, $persist = false)
{
    $user = $this->userMapper->findByEmail($email);
    if (!$user) {
        // Prevent timing attacks.
        password_verify('password', '$2y$12$liVAn/nttQIipJI3LagCAOehLX0iamDjIn2WlX38ZEKS/dDHR3e1W'); // you could also return here and change else-if to if.
    } else if (password_verify($password, $user->getPassword())) {
        // [... session code ...]

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I like that you thought about defending against email harvesting timing attacks (of course, if you have a sign-up page they can be harvested there, but it's still good).

**Comments**

> @return User|void|null The User entity instance if found.

I would be interested in when this returns `void`, and when `null`.

> True for authentication persistence, false if not. (optional)

I would also mention what the default option is (`(optional; false by default)`

> // Issue a data with this data equivalent to the client.

This doesn't sound quite right. `Issue a Cookie`?

**Naming**

- you could use id instead of identifier. It is well understood and shorter, thus might be easier to read (`findByIdentifier` -> `findById`, `$identifier` -> `$id`, etc).
- `getPassword` of user doesn't really express what it does, as it returns a hash. `getPasswordHash` might be a better fit.
- `$data` is very generic, `$cookieData` might be better.
- it might be a bit confusing to have `authenticateUser` in two classes for different activities. I don't have good alternatives, but maybe `authenticateUserByCookie`? But in that case it doesn't fit in with the rest of the methods. You could change the whole naming schema of `AuthenticationStorage` to fix this (this class mainly deals with managing cookies, but the naming doesn't reflect this).

**Misc**

- some of your lines are too long. I would aim for 80 characters per line, you could aim for more, but 195 characters don't fit on a lot of monitors.
- I would probably use a bit less newlines. In `AuthenticationStorage:authenticateUser()` before the `return false;`, and generally in `AuthenticationService`.
- your importing `Authentication` in  `AuthenticationStorage` but are not using it.

Comment: Thanks for the review. **1)** Yes, it should be "Issue a cookie ... ". I used mass correction and this one got changed accidently. **2)** I switched to using the factory to get rid of the SRP violation, and I forgot to delete the import statement of the `Authentication` class. **3)** Do you think my method / class naming is okay?

Comment: @KidDiamond yes, I think it is generally okay. But I added a paragraph with a couple of suggestions.

Comment: I'm thinking about naming it `AuthenticationDataStorage` and it would have the dependency `AuthenticationCookieFactory`. Tbh, I think `authenticateUser` sounds fine. Since it's in a different class it would be safe to assume it does something different as well (internally). Anyways, thanks for your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 5):

In `storeAuthenticationData`, these variables are constants:

> ```
> // Character pool for CryptoRandCharGen::generateString().
> $lowerAlpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
> $upperAlpha = strtoupper($lowerAlpha);
> $digits     = '0123456789';
> $symbols    = './<>?;"\'`!@#$%^&*()[]{}_+=|\-';
> $characters = $lowerAlpha . $upperAlpha . $digits . $symbols;
> ```

Instead of rebuilding `$characters` every time this method is called,
move these outside of the method and do it only once.

This is especially important because you have these duplicated in `updateAuthenticationData` too.

---

The logic of joining and splitting cookie values by `:` appear at multiple places.
It would be better to encapsulate that logic in a dedicated class,
which hides such details as the `:` separator from the rest of the implementation.

---

A minor thing, but in a void method, why not simply `return;` instead of `return null;` ?

Comment: **1)** You mean moving the character pool to the `AuthenticationService` class and inject it from there? **2)** How would you name such a dedicated class? `AuthenticationCookieFactory`? **3)** I guess personal preference.

Comment: 1: you could move them into the constructor; 2: `AuthenticationCookieFactory` sounds fine